# Caching Tokens in Prometheus

Tags: caching, yaml, token, prometheus

I am using OAuth 2.0 with Prometheus, and don't want to generate a new access token every single scrape (which is too often) - I want to generate it once every hour. How can I use a caching system in Prometheus to accomplish this?

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
        - targets: []

rule_files: []

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus"
    metrics_path: "/actuator/prometheus"
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:8080"]
    oauth2:
      client_id: ""
      client_secret_file: ""
      scopes: []
      token_url: ""
```

Comment: Are you confident that the token is being refreshed on each scrape? If so, I think (!?) your solution will be to implement your own token proxy (on `token-url`), cache tokens and refresh them before expiry. I wanted to be able to use Google Identity tokens to access metrics using Google Cloud Run and this involved writing a [gcp-oidc-token-proxy](https://github.com/DazWilkin/gcp-oidc-token-proxy) that, when invoked, returns access|refresh tokens to Prometheus. The response includes the expiry (`ExpiresIn`) value and I assumed (!?) that the token is only refreshed when necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to find a way to  make sure the token actually is being refreshed, and if it is, I'll try using that tool!